# Get values of multiple text input fields with different name?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form with a text input field and option where user can add more than one text input fields (http://prntscr.com/1dikv3) This screenshot will show how it looks.

Now when ever a new field is added using js the name of the field is dynamic say default field has value field and new added field will be have field_2,field_3 and so on...

Now I want to get all the values of these field and insert into DB. I am not sure how can I get the values of all those different named input fields using array or loop?

Here is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    }); });
```

If someone can please guide me I will be thankful.

Thanks

Comment: Take note that jQuery's $.live (http://api.jquery.com/live/) is depricated.

Comment: Are these inputs in an actual form? if so I have a grand plugin for you you will love

Comment: You can check the code in here jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need to distinguish the different fields from one another, use the same name for all, suffixed with `[]`. This will cause PHP to treat them as an array in your $_POST array. You can remove the ID from each new field too. IDs should be unique, and in this instance you're nt using them anyway.

So your function becomes:

```
$(function() {
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');

$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                i--;
        }
        return false;
}); });'
```

In your PHP script you can now access these fields as an array in `$_POST['p_scnt']`

Comment: i went straight for manipulating the form data, but good call on the `[]` value of naming your inputs! That makes a huge difference as well!

Comment: Mike one more thing I need to ask if I have to edit or delete record in DB how will i do that? Say I have to show data in DB using these multiple fields so how will i do that?

Comment: You can manipulate the database with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements. Exactly how you do that depends on the structure of your database and what other data you're handling. There's not enough information here for me to make any real comment. Get started and ask another question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give all the inputs a particular class? If so:

```
var answers = {};
$(".theClass").each(function() {
    var fieldName = $(this).prop("name");
    answers[fieldName] = $(this).val();
});
```

Now you have an object with the input names and the answers.

If you can't give them a class, you could use `$("input[type='text']").each(...`, but I don't know if you have other text inputs on the page. If you do, maybe you could put them in a div with a certain class and use `$(".myDiv").find("input[type='text']").each(...`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, don't use ID's when you know the content is going to be replicated. In short, change them to classes.

**markup**

$('.p_scents') //use a class

**Code**

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('.p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want PHP to loop through all these fields for storing it? Try this:

```
foreach( $_REQUEST as $name=>$value) {
    if( strncmp($name, "p_scnt_", 7) == 0) {
        ... do something with $value ...
    }
}
```

Or, you could go with Mike W's answer which just came in ;)

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in [**Mike W**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473043/get-values-of-multiple-text-input-fields-with-different-name#answer-17473234)'s answer, also make sure, if inputs are getting the same name, be sure to include `[]` after the name so that they will be gathered as an array of data.

---

If all your inputs are in a form, then I would suggest using something like [**`$.ajaxForm`**](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). This plugin makes working with forms EXTREMELY easy. It also incorporates ajax, meaning you completely control the before, after and everything in between.

A basic example:

```
$('#myFormID').ajaxForm({
    target: '#outputID',    //  this would be an element where you might want the echoed data to display, such as "Success!" or "ERROR 404" //  this is not required
    beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options) {
        //  if you return false, the form will not submit, so you can validate form here
        var $return = true;
        //  formData is an array of your input and textarea values
        //  you can manipulate this object or make a straight call like:
        //  also, try using `console.log(formData); return false;` 
        //  and look to make sure the form data being submitted is as you want it
        $("#myFormID input[type=text]").each(function(i) {
            if (somethingIsWrong) {
                $return = false;
            }
        });
        return $return;
    },
    success: function(response, status, xhr, $form) {
        //  response is of course what your back end echoes back
        console.log(response);
        alert(status);
    }
})
```

Again, that nice jQuery plugin is http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Beside the point. OP wants to get at the fields and put them in a database. He can `submit` his form without this.

Comment: @MikeW yea he can submit without it, but I was simply pointing out, this makes submission 100x easier and allows quick manipulation to the data being submitted, thus this is very useful. Don't worry, I gave you a point for your answer too. You were right to mention the `[]` situation